# Nagios check fails: UWSGI CRITICAL: could not connect() to workers Operation now in progress

Tags: nagios, uwsgi

All seems to be installed and work as it should (site/server is running) but keep getting this error:

```
UWSGI CRITICAL: could not connect() to workers Operation now in progress
```

when running:

```
uwsgi --nagios --socket=0.0.0.0:1717
```

My uwsgi.conf (anonymized) is:

```
description "uwsgi instance"
start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [06]

exec uwsgi --master --die-on-term --ini /etc/uwsgi/apps-enabled/my-app.com
```

And my ini file is:

```
[uwsgi]
uid = www-data
gid = www-data
plugins = python

module= wsgi_app
home = /home/django/domains/my-app.com/my-app.com/
pythonpath = /home/django/domains/my-app.com/my-app/uwsgi/
touch-reload = /home/django/domains/my-app.com/my-app/uwsgi/restart.trig
socket = /tmp/my-app.com.socket
logto = /var/log/uwsgi/my-app.com.log
enable-threads = true
single-interpreter = true

listen=4000
threads = 5
workers = 10
master = true
max-requests=1000
buffer-size = 32768
post-buffering = 8192
```

Answer (score 0):

So this was a simple problem of aligning the sockets called. So instead of:

```
uwsgi --nagios --socket=0.0.0.0:1717
```

then I it should be:

```
uwsgi --nagios --socket=/tmp/my-app.com.socket
```

But my problems didn't stop there. Then I ran into a permission problem. This could be fixed by adding `chmod-socket = 666`. But the safety is not perfect in that solution. Instead you can set it to 664, give the user sudoer rights to run the uwsgi command and run the nagios command like this:

```
sudo /usr/local/bin/uwsgi --nagios --socket=/tmp/my-app.com.socket
```

To give your user sudo rights, add this to your /etc/sudoer file (change username to the right one):

```
username ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:/usr/local/bin/uwsgi --nagios --socket=/tmp/my-app.com.socket
```

As I moved from an aptitude install to a pip install then I also had to remove `plugins = python`. And also `listen = 4000` had to be removed, as it was over the limit that I had.

So in the end I have this uwsgi setting:

```
[uwsgi]
uid = www-data
gid = www-data

module = wsgi_app
home = /home/django/domains/my-app.com/my-app.com/
pythonpath = /home/django/domains/my-app.com/my-app/uwsgi/
touch-reload = /home/django/domains/my-app.com/my-app/uwsgi/restart.trig
socket = /tmp/my-app.com.socket
chmod-socket = 664
logto = /var/log/uwsgi/my-app.com.log
enable-threads = true
single-interpreter = true

threads = 5
workers = 10
master = true
max-requests = 1000
buffer-size = 32768
post-buffering = 8192
```